# Qt needs some unknown sdk for Android

Tags: android, qt, sdk

I'm trying to instaill Android Kits for Qt and I have some problems with it. Qt Creator has a setting's menu shows what you need to install. One of requirement things is Android SDK. I used Android Studio to instail some kits, namely SDK Platform for "Android 4.2", "Android 7.0", "Android 7.1" and "Android API 27" (see attachment pictures)[image][image]

But, Qt still says me "Android SDK installation missing necessary packages. Do you want to install the missing packages?" (when I'm pressing 'Yes' - nothing happends). Maybe somebody knows what packages I didn't install yet?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need android studio, just the raw sdk tools, which are 1/5 the download.

Depending on your Qt version, there is a minimum SDK version requirement, currently that's claimed to be API level 21.

Keep in mind that "latest and greatest" versions might be problematic too. Qt takes time to catch up.

Qt doesn't seem to like new versions of the SDK tools, currently at v25 you will need to go back to an older version, for example, Qt 5.9 recommends v23.

Remember that **you have to also specify the target version in your application's android manifest file**.

However, documentation shouldn't always be taken unconditionally, I can for a fact verify that new build tools versions do not work, but I have no problem building and running android apps with Qt 5.9 and 5.10 using the following versions:

```
SDK tools 24.3.4
SDK platform tools 23
API level 18 (note that some newer modules might require newer version)
```

Also, new versions of the android NDK seem to be problematic too. I still use v10 on windows and v11 on linux.

Finally, android some time ago deprecated gcc in favor of clang, so depending on what you installed, you may not have a compatible compiler.

Comment: But, unfortunately, you can't choose a version of Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools, they install the newest versions by default

Comment: Maybe you can download an older package version that comes with older versions of those. IIRC you only need to additionally download api versions, so you can keep the tools the sdk came with and simply take care to not update them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that SDKManager could actually not be run, so the output was void...

My SDKManager (on Windows) could not run because of ClassNotFoundError for java.xml.bind. I added an environment variable to add the module: `set JAVA_OPTS=--add-modules java.se.ee`. After this the SDK Manager pane in Qt Creator became alive and I could update

(note that you have to do it in the correct place, the above command is only valid in the current shell, but if you want to run Qt Creator it's probably easiest to add it to the windows user/system environment variables, through the Configuration Panel)

Answer (score 0):

Install jdk 8.191 (exactly) resolve this for me.